# 5 year UK ban; what can I do?

Tags: uk, passports, indian-citizens, visa-refusals, australia

I have a ban for 5 years for UK visas. Can I still apply to any other countries for a visa and, if so, what type of visa?

Will the ban affect applying for an Australian PR visa. Do I need to wait for 5 years to apply for visas and, after that, would I be free to apply for visa without any restrictions?

If I renew my passport, saying I lost the one I was recently issued, will the new one have the details of earlier refusals? My first passport doesn't have an entry ban stamp on it.

1. Passport one (2006-2016); during this time I went to the UK
2. May 2016, returned to India, applied for new passport in June 2016; this new passport has the same number as the first passport.
3. If I apply for another passport, saying I lost of my recently renewed one, will the replacement again have the same number?

I want to hide my entire UK history and make a clean application for Austalian permanent residence.

Comment: if you could get out of a ban by just claiming you lost your passport and getting a new one, a ban would be pretty pointless, wouldn't it?

Comment: Try this and you will screw up your chances of getting visa to any other country ever again.

Answer (score 5):

The Australian permanent resident form includes a question similar to the following:

> Have you, or any other person included in this application, ever been removed, deported or excluded from any country (including Australia)? (yes/no)

If your ban was due to overstaying a visa, there's another question for that too. You will have to answer "yes", whether you apply today, 5 years, or 30 years from now.

When you answer "yes":

> If you answered '**Yes**' to any of the questions at Question 68, you must state who it applies to and give ALL relevant details.

You will have to explain your ban, why/how it happened, along with any supporting documentation you have received from the UK.

Your signature on the form says (among other things):

> - the information I have supplied in this application is complete, correct
>     and up-to-date in every detail.
> - I authorise the Australian Government to make any enquiries
>     necessary to determine my eligibility for permanent stay in Australia,
>     and to use any information supplied in this application for that
>     purpose.
> - I understand that if any fraudulent documents or false or misleading
>     information has been provided with this application, or if I fail to
>     satisfy the Minister of my identity, my application may be refused and
>     I, and any other member of my family unit, may become unable to be
>     granted a visa for specified periods of time.
> - if documents are found to be fraudulent or information to be
>     incorrect after the grant of a visa, the visa may subsequently be
>     cancelled.

So, they can (and probably will) ask the UK about you.

Note that disclosing and explaining your ban does not automatically exclude you from obtaining an Australian visa. However, they will undoubtedly take the relevant circumstances into consideration when processing your application.

Comment: And if you lie at this point, then you're going to enter a near-permanent ban status.